# Setting On Click Listener For A Dynamic ListView

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

thanks for always being available...

I have been able to populate my ListView with information i have in the database.

Now, I want setOnClickListener for the items to go to different pages. Currently, I am using a "switch(position)" construct, but it doesn't function appropriately since I can't hard code how many items would be on the ListView.

Please, kindly help me out on this one.

public class SurveyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
SQLiteDatabase db;
DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

String listItem = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_survey);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Add new survey", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();

            PopupMenu pop = new PopupMenu(SurveyActivity.this, fab);
            pop.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.addsurvey_menu, pop.getMenu());
            pop.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your choice is to " + item.getTitle().toString().toUpperCase() + " a survey form", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    switch (item.getItemId()) {

                        case R.id.c:
                            //Takes admin to page where survey is created

                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CreateSurvey.class);
                            startActivity(i);

                        case R.id.d:
                            //gets ready created XML forms from server

                        case R.id.r:
                            //refreshes and updates survey list from db

                    }

                    return true;
                }
            });

            pop.show();

        }
    });

    db = helper.getReadableDatabase();

    //Cursor crs = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbNames", null);
    Cursor crs=db.query("tbNames",new String[]{ "names"},null,null,null,null,null);

    if(crs.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            listItem =crs.getString(0);
            list.add(listItem);

        }while(crs.moveToNext());
    }

    ListView surveyList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.surveylist);

    ArrayAdapter<String> aAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    surveyList.setAdapter(aAdapter);
    registerForContextMenu(surveyList);

    surveyList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            switch (position) {

                case 0:
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), hivActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SurveyActivity.this, CreatedSurveyActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

My app would allow users create multiple surveys which would show up in the LIstView.

The problem is how to set Listeners for the items dynamically too.

Comment: post your whole code

Comment: Have you tried creating a custom ArrayAdapter and setting an onClickListener to the convertViews? Maybe even override the getItemViewType(int position) method to declare different view types for your listview children, which you can use to determine what the click event should be. That should be a solid solution.

Comment: Pls kindly post an example or a link on how to achieve this

Comment: Could you tell what actions should be performed on each item in the list? Are they all different, or only the first item differs from all others?

Comment: the first item is different from the others in the sense that it has an already created activity which has its own unique interface and content. The other items share a single activity but have different contents which are pulled from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code

```
surveyList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        if (position == 0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), hivActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SurveyActivity.this, CreatedSurveyActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
});
```

First item will call `hivActivity` and all other items will call `CreatedSurveyActivity`. If you need to pass something to the `CreatedSurveyActivity` put it into the intent, like this `intent.putExtra("position" position);`

Comment: Thanks, this works...I never thought of it. How embarrassing. Also, I added default to my switch to replace other cases and it worked too

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use setOn**Item**ClickListener()

Answer (score 0):

Posting your code would be helpful, however an approach that can often help in similar situations is:

1. Set a tag on each view, as you generate it. For example, the item ID, or just an incrementer.
2. The onClickListener will receive the view as a parameter. The tag can then be retrieved from it.
3. This tag can then be matched to page names, page URLs, or any other information you're trying to load.

Comment: Please enlighten me more on how to do this. An example should suffice.